# Resolve Lord's Paradox with principal components analysis (orthogonal distance regression)?

Tags: pca, least-squares, paradox

I've been reading Judea Pearl's description of Lord's Paradox in his 2018 book *The Book of Why: The New Science of Cause and Effect*, in which he presents the following plot:

[image]

In this special case where the data points lie along the same diagonal, if Statistician 2 conducts a regression of Final Weight on Initial Weight using **principal components analysis** (or orthogonal distance regression), wouldn't that eliminate the different findings of the two statisticians and resolve the paradox?

Using PCA to fit a line that minimizes the average squared distance between the points and the line would produce a single fitted line for men and women, rather than two separate regression lines when the average SSE for Final Weight is minimized with least squares.

Comment: I thought principal components analysis regression involved  regressing the dependent variable against the leading component(s) of the explanatory variables.  Your chart seems to suggest finding the principal component of the combination of $W_I$ and $W_F$, which is a different thing given that  $W_F$ is not an explanatory variable

Comment: @Henry Yes, I should have specified orthogonal distance regression of $W_F$ on $W_I$ with an additional independent variable for sex (Dining Room A or B). The weird thing is when I attempt to randomly generate data points for men and women that lie along the 45 degree line of correlation, then regress lines on each group, I get intercepts close to zero instead of the intercept offset described in literature & diagrams on Lord's Paradox.

Comment: I am not sure that kind of approach lends itself to casual inference; Galton's original regression of children's heights against their parents clearly produced an intercept and he did it that way round because he thought the parents affected the children rather than the other way round.  [My attempt to produce Lord's paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522134/can-lords-paradox-be-caused-by-regression-to-the-mean) suggested it might be a regression-to-the-mean effect resulting from forcing $W_F$ to have the same distribution as $W_I$